# Skip a particular item in ComboBox .setItemLabelGenerator()

Tags: java, vaadin

I am currently working on a custom ComboBox where an employee needs to select a replacement for himself. The problem is that while I'm adding all the empolyees in the combobox I want to skip myself (cause I shouldn't be able to select myself as a replacement for myself). How can I do this?

```
replacement.setItemLabelGenerator(Employee -> {
    if (!currentEmployee.getName().equals(Employee.getName())) {
        return Employee.getName();
    } else {
        return "current Employee Name that doesn't need to apear"; //this needs skipped or ignored
    }
});
```

Comment: You must filter the list you are passing to setItems

Answer (score 3):

You can either filter the list of items filled in as mentioned in the comment.

Or you could switch to the Select component which supports disabled items, but has a slightly different behaviour than the ComboBox

https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/select/#disabled-items